# Не получается присвоить новую главную страницу в приложении Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

у меня есть многостраничное приложение, в App я присваиваю MainPage страницу "MainPage".

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
                    {
                        BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("4CAF50")
                    };
```

После чего, у меня идет проверка на определенное условие и если оно выполнено, то я назначаю новую главную страницу(BetaTestEnd) с помощью строчки:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new BetaTestEnd());
```

И у меня не присваивается и ничего не происходит после этих действий. Cтоит отметить, что у меня есть кнопка, который выполняет такой же функционал и при нажатии на кнопку MainPage изменяется.
Также стоит отметить, что MainPage имеет структуру MasterDetailPage.

Comment: Если вы используете `NavigationPage`, то пользуйтесь правильно `await Navigation.PushAsync (new BetaTestEnd());` документация [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)

Comment: @Bulson добрый день, в моем случае наоборот, я должен получить страницу, с которой нельзя будет перейти назад, поэтому я присваиваю MainPage мою страницу. То же самое будет, если я уберу ```new NavigationPage``` из строчки